# GASを使ったデスクトップアプリケーションのデータ操作

Tags: c#, google-apps-script

こんばんは。

現在、デスクトップアプリケーションでGASを使った業務アプリの開発中です。

その際、クライアント側とGoogleスプレッドシートを接続し、クライアントにて参加シートの作成、データ入力、データ編集、データ参照を行いたいと思っております。

しかし、実際に調べてもGASの接続方法は出てくるのですが、本当に必要である、入力編集参照が出て来ません。

実際にやりたいことは
・クライアント側で年月日、曜日、売り上げ、人数を入力し、保存を押すとGoogleスプレッドシートに書き込み（その際、日付が若いものが上に来る形）。
・対象の年月のシートがない場合は「xxxx年xx月売り上げ」というようなタイトルでシートの新規作成
・クライアント側で指定した年月日のデータを編集（ない場合はクライアント側にてデータがない旨を表示します」
・クライアント側にて、データをフル取得し、前年比較、前月比較、前日比較、各曜日比較（月曜であれば月曜のデータのみ表示等）。

の以上となります。

クライアント側はUnityC#を使っています。
これは本来他の開発環境が良いのですが、自分が使い慣れている点、またスマートフォンへの移行も可能な点があるため試験的に使用しています。

一番の不明点は、UnityC#の変数をGASで受け取る方法です。 
逆は調べると出て来るのですが、C#側からが不明です。

まだまだプログラミングの世界に入って経験が浅い為、初歩的な質問かも知れませんが、どうぞご教示お願い致します。

Comment: 外部アプリからGASへ値を渡す方法はいくつかありますが、シンプルな方法としては[Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)が宜しいかと思います。アプリ側からGETあるいはPOSTリクエストを使ってデプロイしたWeb Appsへ値を送り、GAS側のスクリプト（Google Apps Script）を実行させることが可能です。Web Appsのデプロイ時の設定で、質問中のスプレッドシートについてユーザのGoogleDrive内のものを使うかオーナーのものを使うかを指定することができます。また、GASを使わずにアプリ側のスクリプトのみでスプレッドシートを直接編集したい場合は[Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/?hl=ja)を使用することで実現できます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
大まかですが、あらかた内容を理解することができました。
WebAppsというものを知らなかったため、今度こちらを使用して構築していこうと思います。
誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。